# move snapshot to images folder

Tags: react-native, snapshot

I am building an app for iOS with React-native, and I use my code to capture a screenshot successfully. The problem is that I want to move the snapshot to the Images folder so it is easily accessible by the user.
I use the following code:

```
    snapshot = async () => {

    const targetPixelCount = 1080; // If you want full HD pictures
    const pixelRatio = PixelRatio.get(); // The pixel ratio of the device
    // pixels * pixelratio = targetPixelCount, so pixels = targetPixelCount / pixelRatio
    const pixels = targetPixelCount / pixelRatio;

    const result = await Expo.takeSnapshotAsync(this, {
      result: 'file',
      height: pixels,
      width: pixels,
      quality: 1,
      format: 'png',
    });

    if (result) {
      //RNFS.moveFile(result, 'Documents/snapshot.png');
      Alert.alert('Snapshot', "Snapshot saved to " + result);
    }
    else {
      Alert.alert('Snapshot', "Failed to save snapshot");
    }
  }
```

Does anybody know how to move the image to the Images Folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the RN CameraRoll Module: **https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll**